# Is there a way to match any decimal number with T-SQL 'LIKE' expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

For example, something like:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '[0-9]n.[0-9]n'`

Of course I know the syntax above will not work, but I m trying to explain: n digits, followed by a period, followed by n digits.
Thanks

Comment: If that is always the format, why don't you store it in two `int`-columns?

Comment: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE '%[0-9].[0-9]%'

Comment: Is the column not decimal?

Comment: Correct. The column is nvarchar(50), and the intention here is to extract values that are convertible to decimal.

Comment: @Kambiz Are you trying to match a specific number of digits?

Comment: No I was actually trying to match any decimal with any number of digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use following patters for **unsigned** decimal values:

```
SELECT  *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN (x.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%' /*OR x.Col1 LIKE '.%[0-9]%' OR x.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%.' OR x.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'*/) 
            AND x.Col1 NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'  
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS IsDecimal,
        ISNUMERIC(x.Col1) AS [IsNumeric]
FROM (
    SELECT '1.23' UNION ALL SELECT '.23' UNION ALL SELECT '1.'  UNION ALL SELECT '123'  UNION ALL 
    SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT '' UNION ALL SELECT '1A.23'  UNION ALL SELECT '1.2A3'  UNION ALL SELECT 'A.B'  UNION ALL 
    SELECT '.' UNION ALL SELECT '$' 
) x(Col1)

/*
Col1  IsDecimal   IsNumeric
----- ----------- -----------
1.23  1           1
.23   0           1
1.    0           1
123   0           1
NULL  0           0
      0           0
1A.23 0           0
1.2A3 0           0
A.B   0           0
.     0           1
$     0           1
*/
```

If you uncomment `/*OR x.Col1 LIKE '.%[0-9]%' OR x.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%.' OR x.Col1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'*/` then `.23 , 1. and 123` will be considered (also) valid decimal values.

Comment: This fits the bill for what I intended.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, the [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) in MS SQL only allows for single character matching.

you could do: `[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]` To Match `00.00`

Or any combination like that, but it does not have a count or other operator like you are looking for.

Comment: I was hoping that would nt be the case. But seems like it is.

Comment: @Kambiz what is so difficult about that syntax.  Decimal only supports up to 38.

Comment: It s not.  But I was trying to match any (variable) number of digits. Basically matching any decimals.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need exactly n or just anything that will cast to decimal

```
select cast(varDec as Decimal(p,s)) 
where varDec not like '%[^.1-9]%' 
and varDec not like '%.%.%'
and len(varDec) > 0 
and varDec <> '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PATINDEX to pattern matching in MS SQL

Two match two digits followed by . and two digits.

```
SELECT *  FROM myTable WHERE PatIndex('[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]', myColumn) >0
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you are looking for this instead?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(myColumn) = 1
```

Comment: No, don't use ISNUMERIC(). Not only does it not have the ability to specify n digits before and after the decimal, [it has a slew of other issues](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html).

Comment: @AaronBertrand This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you may be throwing up unnecessary roadblocks. The OP wants to "extract values that are convertible to decimal".  `ISNUMERIC()` could be exactly what he is looking for.

Comment: Disagree completely. For one, they only want numbers with a specific number of digits before and after the decimal. How does this possibly do that? For another, how do you convert `2e5`, `.` or `$` to decimal? They don't convert (but they do return true for `ISNUMERIC()`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand you sound like you have put some thought into this.  Why not type up an answer?